# Replies that are deleted aren't removed from the feed

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

If you are notified by a comment on one of your posts, and that comment is later deleted, the notification is usually removed from the inbox. But this does not happen on the feed of the Android app.

I have a comment reply in my feed that has been deleted for several days now, and it is still visible there. Additionally I get the error "Loading the question failed" when trying to access it.

The expected behaviour compared to the website would be to remove replies from the feed when those comments are deleted. Additionally, if a user still manages to follow such a reply when the comment is deleted, loading the question should not fail.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's not a dupe, my post is about the feed, not about the OS-level Android notifications. It's an entirely different issue (as you can also see in the different errors that occur).

Comment: I was always under the impression it's the same thing i.e. the feed showing various items, notifications are part of those items. Was I wrong?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It seems to work differently, the notification is gone from the inbox in the app, but not from the feed.

Comment: Fair enough, didn't know that. Vote retracted.